# variable declared and not used in Go

Tags: go

In the following code:

```
func PrimeF(n uint64) {
var i,t uint64 = 2,3


for ; i < n; {
    if n%i == 0 {
        n /= i
    }

   }
}
```

Why do I get the error message: "t declared and not used"?

Comment: you can also mute veritable like this: **var i,_ uint64 = 2,3**

Comment: Your post is a statement, not a question. Can you phrase it so it actually asks something (that way, other users can understand what they should answer)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you declared a variable called `t` here:

```
var i,t uint64 = 2,3
```

but never used that variable.

Comment: Oh! Right.
I'm did not know.
Thank you quick answer.